# Pass a list as inventory to ansible_runner python module

Tags: python, ansible-runner

I want to use ansible_runner to do some parsing on hosts.
I have a script which  gathers a list of hosts from a database and then I want to pass that list to ansible_runner python module without writing the "inventory" to disk.

I tried to do like this based on what I could understand from the documentation:

```
>> import ansible_runner
>> hostlist = ['host1', 'host2']
>>> r = ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir='.',inventory=hostlist, playbook='check_ping.yml')
```

I appears that each element in the list that I pass is taken as if it was an inventory file located in the inventory directory. I just would like to use the elements of the list as hosts to be used and in this case do a ping.

my question is how to pass to the ansible_runner python module an inventory variable whether is a json file, list, dictionary that it does not exists anywhere on disk? and let ansible connect to those.

Answer (score 2):

Build a nested dictionary as shown. Give an Iterable *hostsiwant*

```
hosts = {r:None for r in hostsiwant}
inv = {'all': {'hosts': hosts}}
r = ansible_runner.run(inventory=inv, #remaining arguments as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ansible_runner.run()` accepts following values for `inventory` parameter.

1. Path to the inventory file in the private_data_dir
2. Native python dict supporting the YAML/json inventory structure
3. A text INI formatted string
4. A list of inventory sources, or an empty list to disable passing
   inventory

Default value, if not passed, for this parameter is `private_data_dir/inventory` directory. Passing this parameter overrides the inventory directory/file. [Documentation here](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.6/source/ansible_runner.html)

In the code sample given in the question, a list of hosts is passed as a value for `inventory` param and as per design, the list values are considered as list of inventory source files.

**Examples:**

- **Passing inventory as dictionary:**

A dictionary with all required details can be built using python and passed as `ansible_runner.run(inventory=my_inventory)`.

`web_server` and `backend_server` will become host group name.

```
import ansible_runner

my_inventory = {
  "web_server": {
    "hosts": {
      "webserver_1.example.com": {
        "ansible_user": "test",
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "test_user.pem",
        "ansible_host": "webserver_1.example.com"
      },
      "webserver_2.example.com": {
        "ansible_user": "test",
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "test_user.pem",
        "ansible_host": "webserver_1.example.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "backend_server": {
    "hosts": {
      "backend_server_1.example.com": {
        "ansible_user": "test",
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "test_user.pem",
        "ansible_host": "backend_server_1.example.com"
      }
    }
  }
}

runner_result = ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir='.', inventory=my_inventory, playbook='check_ping.yml')
print(runner_result.stats)
```

Note: Doing this will save the contents in `hosts.json` file in `private_data_dir/inventory` directory.

- **Write inventory file:**

Other way is writing host details in YAML/json format into a file inside `private_data_dir/inventory` directory.